# ReactiveUI - why do these {Binding }s work?

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I have posted a question on codereview (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124300/reactiveui-and-wpf-reusing-a-value-to-update-multiple-properties). My latest effort at answering that question has led me to the following code, which seems to work, but I'm not sure what mechanism is actually providing the functionality!

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TestHumanName.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="392" Width="391">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Full" />
            <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Full, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Button Content="Go"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Title" />
            <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding NameObject.Title, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="First" />
        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding NameObject.First, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Middle" />
        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding NameObject.Middle, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Last" />
        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding NameObject.Last, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;
using TestHumanName.ViewModel;

namespace TestHumanName
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Full).Where(x => x != null).Select(x => ParseName(x))
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.NameObject, out __oapName);
    }

    private string __sFull;
    public string Full
    {
        get { return __sFull; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref __sFull, value); }
    }

    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<Name> __oapName;
    public Name NameObject { get { return __oapName.Value; } }

    //NAME PARSING CODE BELOW THIS LINE

        public class Name
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string First { get; set; }
            public string Middle { get; set; }
            public string Last { get; set; }
            public string Suffix { get; set; }
        }

        public Name ParseName(string s)
        {
            Name n = new Name();

            // Split on period, commas or spaces, but don't remove from results.
            List<string> parts = Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=[., ])").ToList();

            // Remove any empty parts
            for (int x = parts.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
                if (parts[x].Trim() == "")
                    parts.RemoveAt(x);

            if (parts.Count > 0)
            {
                // Might want to add more to this list
                string[] prefixes = { "mr", "mrs", "ms", "dr", "miss", "sir", "madam", "mayor", "president" };

                // If first part is a prefix, set prefix and remove part
                string normalizedPart = parts.First().Replace(".", "").Replace(",", "").Trim().ToLower();
                if (prefixes.Contains(normalizedPart))
                {
                    n.Title = parts[0].Trim();
                    parts.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }

            if (parts.Count > 0)
            {
                // Might want to add more to this list, or use code/regex for roman-numeral detection
                string[] suffixes = { "jr", "sr", "i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v", "vi", "vii", "viii", "ix", "x", "xi", "xii", "xiii", "xiv", "xv" };

                // If last part is a suffix, set suffix and remove part
                string normalizedPart = parts.Last().Replace(".", "").Replace(",", "").Trim().ToLower();
                if (suffixes.Contains(normalizedPart))
                {
                    n.Suffix = parts.Last().Replace(",", "").Trim();
                    parts.RemoveAt(parts.Count - 1);
                }
            }

            // Done, if no more parts
            if (parts.Count == 0)
                return n;

            // If only one part left...
            if (parts.Count == 1)
            {
                // If no prefix, assume first name, otherwise last
                // i.e.- "Dr Jones", "Ms Jones" -- likely to be last
                if (n.Title == "")
                    n.First = parts.First().Replace(",", "").Trim();
                else
                    n.Last = parts.First().Replace(",", "").Trim();
            }

            // If first part ends with a comma, assume format:
            //   Last, First [...First...]
            else if (parts.First().EndsWith(","))
            {
                n.Last = parts.First().Replace(",", "").Trim();
                for (int x = 1; x < parts.Count; x++)
                    n.First += parts[x].Replace(",", "").Trim() + " ";
                n.First = n.First.Trim();
            }

            // Otherwise assume format:
            // First [...Middle...] Last

            else
            {
                n.First = parts.First().Replace(",", "").Trim();
                n.Last = parts.Last().Replace(",", "").Trim();
                for (int x = 1; x < parts.Count - 1; x++)
                    n.Middle += parts[x].Replace(",", "").Trim() + " ";
                if (n.Middle != null) n.Middle = n.Middle.Trim();
            }

            return n;
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm failing to understand, is how I can replace the value of the `NameObject` property, and the `{Binding ...}s` magically know that they should update. Surely, replacing the contents of the `NameObject` property doesn't call OnPropertyChanged on it's child properties ... The `Name` class doesn't even implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

So, what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: A window has a Paint Event that controls when a windows get updated.  The Paint Event gets called when data is changed in standard Net Library Classes.  If you build your own class then you have to call the Window Paint Event.

Comment: I don't see how the Paint Event relates to a {Binding }?

Comment: It is not the binding that not working.  It is the updating that isn't occurring.  Changing the binding won't automatically change what is displayed in the window.  Paint has to be called to tell the window to update.

Comment: Sorry, i think you are not understanding my question. The `Binding` IS WORKING.

Comment: You said "{Binding ...}s magically know that they should update".  The windows REFRESH functions take the binding and puts the data into the window.  The refresh is done in the Paint Event.

Comment: I did say that. I also said some other things which amount to me asking a question other than the one you are trying to answer! Thanks anyway though :0)

Comment: Specifcally, in the context of ReactiveUI, what is causing the bindings to work? It has nothing to do with Paint events.

Comment: It is sometimes hard with Net Library to see all the intermediate operation that occur.  I know the windows mechanism that must occur.  It looks like the method RaiseAndSetIfChanged() in RectiveUI is really calling the paint event.

Comment: @jdweng this is WPF.  Data Binding has nothing to do with paint events.

Comment: It is a windows application!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## General concept

I think from where your misunderstanding comes from.
What you do here:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Full).Where(x => x != null).Select(x => ParseName(x))
        .ToProperty(this, x => x.NameObject, out __oapName);
```

Means that whenever `Full` property changes, fire `ParseName` method, so that it will update property `_oapName`.
But, since `_oapName` is **ObservableAsPropertyHelper** type, that is the heart of `Rx`, it will notify UI on its own.

**As documentation states:**

> This initialises the 'put yours here' property (an
>   ObservableAsPropertyHelper property) as a property that will be
>   updated with the current search text length every time it changes. The
>   property cannot be set in any other manner and **raises change
>   notifications**, so can itself be used in a WhenAny expression **or a
>   binding**.

**Source:**
http://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/when-any/index.html

## Behind the scenes

If we take a look on signature of `ToProperty`:

```
public static ObservableAsPropertyHelper<TRet> ToProperty<TObj, TRet>(
    this IObservable<TRet> This,
    TObj source,
    Expression<Func<TObj, TRet>> property,
    out ObservableAsPropertyHelper<TRet> result,
    TRet initialValue = default(TRet),
    IScheduler scheduler = null)
    where TObj : IReactiveObject
    {
        var ret = source.observableToProperty(This, property, initialValue, scheduler);

        result = ret;
        return ret;
    }
```

we'll see that what it actually does, is just call an extension method `observableToProperty` to produce **ObservableAsPropertyHelper**.
To be even more precise, inside `observableToProperty` we can see few lines like this:

```
var ret = new ObservableAsPropertyHelper<TRet>(observable,
            _ => This.raisePropertyChanged(name),
            _ => This.raisePropertyChanging(name),
            initialValue, scheduler);
```

and keeping in mind that:

- `This` (kudos for variable name) in `observableToProperty` is of type `TObj` with constrain of `where TObj : IReactiveObject`,
- `name` is name of property you've passed to `Expression<Func<TObj, TRet>> property`, ie. in your case `name` from `x => x.NameObject` will be **NameObject**

it will end up raising **RaisePropertyChanged** on parent `ReactiveObject` of `NameObject` which is **MainViewModel**.

**Source code**: [ObservableAsPropertyHelper.cs @ ReactiveUI on Github](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/ab62c17be9136afa245995118ebffa81a0673546/ReactiveUI/ObservableAsPropertyHelper.cs)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That makes sense, and i see from the reference that nested properties can be watched, but in the example given in the reference, the nested properties are explicitly stated eg `this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Foo.Bar.Baz);`. In my xaml, I bind to `NameObject.Title` for example, which is an instantiation of the `Name` class, which isn't a ReactiveObject. And as i don't explicitly state the nested properties in my code, I'm having a hard time seeing how those properties are notifying about changes!

Comment: Since `WhenAny` uses `out`, it means that output of `ParseName` was assigned as new value (reference actually, to be precise) of property `_oapName`. You smelled it right that property of property `NameObject` doesn't raise notification. The whole `_oapName` raises the notification as object wrapped by `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` has changed (ie. property of OAPH has raised the notification).

Comment: ok. cool. So i guess I now have to ask, how far down a tree of nested properties does that work? If i had `NameObject.Title.Length`, does that still work? Are the {Binding}s smart enough to know that `NameObject` has changed, so any nested property belonging to `NameObject` must have changed? I can't find a definitive answer in the docs...

Comment: From what I can see, docs for `ReactiveUI` are still halfway there, but reading through [Github code](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/ab62c17be9136afa245995118ebffa81a0673546/ReactiveUI/ObservableAsPropertyHelper.cs) I can see that it notifies on object change per se, so changes to properties doesn't matter as you've swapped the whole object, ie. all properties should be swapped.

Comment: I guess additional misunderstanding might come from `ReactiveUI` being backed up by `System.Reactive` which is not so easy to understand from scratch itself (ie. what's going on behind exposed API).

Comment: Can i ask which lines of code you draw your conclusion from? I've not delved that far into the source so it's difficult to see which bit 'notifies on object change'. I totally understand what you mean though :0)

Comment: If you take a look on `ToProperty<TObj, TRet>` method, you'll see that it actually creates an `out ObservableAsPropertyHelper<TRet> result` using `observableToProperty<TObj, TRet>`function, that wires changes of wrapped object to raise notification changed of parent `ReactiveObject`. So your `_oapName` on reference change will raise parent `MainViewModel` notification. I guess I move some of the info up so others can benefit from it too. :)

Comment: That is a superb answer! Thank you. I guess one of two things must be going on ... either the `ReactiveObject` class keeps track of all the properties that currently have a `{Binding }`, or, because the object has been replaced it just raises change notifications for every property since 'all properties change when an object changes'. Would love to know the answer to that too, but I'm accepting this now because it's spot on! :0)